# How to push the UI log to Server(Having endpoint)?

Tags: node.js, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have android app which is build by using flutter basically it's a app which use the http library to get the response from Json file.

After that i bind that response to the flutter UI so i have a query like how to push the UI log to the server. I have the server which has the log directory so basically i have to push the logs to this folder which is located on the server.

I did one task like show the logs into the console in runtime but how can i push this log to the server in flutter.

This is the basic flutter code by using logging library in flutter.

```
import 'package:logging/logging.dart';

Logger.root.level = Level.ALL;
  Logger.root.onRecord.listen((record) {
    print('${record.level.name}: ${record.time}: ${record.message}');
  });

logger.info('Device Types: $items');
```

So this is the basic implementation so can anyone suggest me how to push this log to the server.

Thanks.